# ARM Programming - Spilling Register Significance

Tags: architecture, arm

I am learning about procedures in ARM, and my professor's lecture notes has the following code as an example:

```
int leaf_examp(int g, int h,
int i, int j)
{
int f;
f = (g+h)-(i+j);
return f;
}
```

He has given the following as the corresponding ARM code for the above procedure:

```
Leaf_examp:
SUB sp, sp, #12
STR r6, [sp,#8]
STR r5, [sp,#4]
STR r4, [sp,#0]
ADD r5, r0, r1
ADD r6, r2, r3
SUB r4, r5, r6
MOV r0, r4
LDR r4, [sp,#0]
LDR r5, [sp,#4]
LDR r6, [sp,#8]
ADD sp, sp, #12
MOV pc, lr
```

I don't understand what the lines which contain "sp" mean in the above code. I referred for it on my professor's lecture notes and it just says that it refers to Spilling Registers. I just Googled for it but I don't understand it well enough to make sense of the above code. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Your professor is not showing code produced by a real compiler. With the ABI, R0-3 are used for function arguments and they are volatile, and expected to be destroyed by the caller. There is no need to spill registers. A compiled function is only four instructions and involves no `memory` operands.  I guess he has done this for educational purposes.  However, I would hope someone looking at this question doesn't believe this is real compiler code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp` is the Stack Pointer. It's an alias for `r13`. In this case, the code is reserving 12 bytes of space on the stack to preserve the original values of `r4-r6` since those registers are used for calculations inside the function. On exit, the original values are restored from the stack into those registers.